# How do I make Eclipse set the preference "Refresh Automatically" by default?

Tags: eclipse, default, preferences

I have an Eclipse application that suffers from the "out of sync" problem. This is solved by setting the "Refresh automatically" preference.

As this will always be needed I would like to set this preference automatically and not
require the user to remember to do it every time the workspace is changed.
How can this be done?
I have found references to setting preferences, but they require knowledge of the actual name of the preference.

Answer (score 0):

You find workspace refresh settings in the file:

```
$workspace.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
```

But there is no preference called "Refresh automatically". Just "Build automatically" and "Refresh on access"

The property for "Build automatically" is:

```
description.autobuilding=true
```

And for "Refresh on access":

```
refresh.lightweight.enabled=true
```

This is a bit tricky, but you can set them manually (e.g. with FileWriter) for example in the Application.java. But be aware of a eclipse product update. Hope this helps.